# How to call function other model in one model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two function in my model, I want to call other model in my model, but actually error array to string conversion.
This is my code:

```php
public function get_detail_activity()
{
  $status=$activity;//call function model activity
  $query=$this->db->query("SELECT 
  t_trx_activity.activity_id FROM t_trx_activity
  JOIN t_trx_activity_detail ON
  t_trx_activity_detail.activity_id =t_trx_activity.activity_id
  WHERE t_trx_activity.activity_id = '".$status."' //function put here");

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }

public function activity()
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT t_trx_activity.activity_id
        FROM t_trx_activity
        ORDER BY
        t_trx_activity.activity_id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $nik=$this->session->userdata('nik');

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

How to call function other model in one model?

Comment: I'm not following what you are trying to do here... Can you have another go at trying to explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want show data from  get_detail_activity and where(from function activity)

Comment: so, is it the same model or a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not calling the function properly, try the following,

```
public function get_detail_activity()
{
    $status= $this->activity();//call function model activity
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT 
          t_trx_activity.activity_id FROM t_trx_activity
          JOIN t_trx_activity_detail ON
          t_trx_activity_detail.activity_id =t_trx_activity.activity_id
          WHERE t_trx_activity.activity_id = '".$status."'");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}


 public function activity()
 {
     $query=$this->db->query("SELECT t_trx_activity.activity_id
         FROM t_trx_activity
         ORDER BY
         t_trx_activity.activity_id DESC LIMIT 1");
         $nik=$this->session->userdata('nik');

     if($query->num_rows()>0)
     {
         return $query->row()->activity_id;
     }
     else
     {
         return 0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: in which line ? i am pretty sure the error also shows the line number ?

Comment: thanks for accepting, as this solved your problem, also consider voting up. regards.